How can the ions in intergalactic and interstellar gas held together?
The interstellar and intergalactic medium contain huge amounts of free ions (both free protons and electrons).
However, when these particles are not stabilized in an atom because they are excited, as they have the same charge, they should repel each other by electromagnetic forces, so how can they be held together and not fly away to infinity?
And in the case that proton decay is a real thing, in the far future, how will this gas held together once protons "disappear" from this medium?

Well, those electrons have something to do with it…

@JonCuster but if they are free, shouldn't they repel each other and fly away from the system? What is exactly holding them together?

I have read that interstellar and intergalactic medium is supposed to be mostly empty, having a very low matter density of just several hydrogen atoms per meter cube and occasional passing photons?

Plasmas are net neutral. If all the protons fly away what will the electrons do?

To put it another way: why do atoms not fly apart despite all the clouded-around electrons repulsing each other? It turns out to be the same reason: the system is electrically neutral and, more importantly, stable. There would be an issue if there were a net charge imbalance in the Universe.

If electrons were to attempt to separate, protons, being oppositely charged, would be naturally drawn to follow them due to the fundamental electromagnetic attraction. However, proton decay, while theoretically possible, occurs over such an unfathomably long timescale that all stars would have extinguished long before it could have any significant effect on matter. In such a scenario, the absence of stars and energy sources would mean that the conditions required for plasma, which depends on the ionization of atoms, would no longer exist.

To clarify, if this answer feels off-topic: eventually there will be a charge imbalance from proton decay leaving there fewer positive charges than negative charges, but at that point all the stars'll be dead anyway so "intergalactic" won't make much sense.

If you have a cloud of completely ionised, net-neutral gas and then you try to remove some of the charged constituents - say the electrons have a higher velocity dispersion - then all that will happen is that you would make the centre more positively charged and this would provide a restoring force that would prevent the electrons leaving.
In practice you will get some charge separation in this manner until an equilibrium is achieved with the centre of the cloud having a net positive charge whilst the electrons would have a broader distribution.
As an example, the greater mobility of electrons in the solar wind leaves the Sun with a small ($\sim 100$C) positive charge. What is the electric charge of the Sun and its corona?
As for proton decay, I'm no expert on the decay mechanisms, but those proposed would generally conserve electric charge (e.g., decay to a positron and neutral pion) so really doesn't have much bearing on the problem.

Interesting. So even without proton decay, we can have a clustering of electrons separatedly from a clustering of protons? Then, if proton decay even occurs this wouldn't perturb this configuration? Could this actually occur and be stable in a interstellar/intergalactic cloud in nature? @ProfRob
