Can a Wigner crystal form spontaneously, or it will always need an external confining force field?
As far as I know, a Wigner crystal could be formed spontaneously from a free electron "cloud" with the right conditions (low temperature and electron density). Would it be stable and not susceptible to being separated through the mechanism described here?:
G. Schmidt, Physics of High Temperature Plasmas (2nd ed.), pg. 72*
And if it would be susceptible to being destabilized, would it be stable if the system had minimal energy?
*https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/350218/

Please don't link to personal clouds, see this.

No, Wigner crystals have net negative charge and the electrons repel each other - it will fly apart without a confining force, as the Schmidt virial argument shows. So you need to add a confining force, whether gravity (but self-gravity is not enough for electrons) or an external field.

Do you mean net negative charge instead? Or what am I missing? Anyway, in the Jellium you consider a positive background, no?

@TobiasFünke - Yes, of course it should be negative! Will fix it.

Ok. But can you address my other point? As I said, the Jellium model is charge neutral, no? Am I missing something? If so, could you provide a reference please?

could the confining force be instated in the form ProfRob described in this other question (physics.stackexchange.com/questions/825340/…)? @AndersSandberg

@vengaq - In the jellium model there is some background material with positive charge. Sure, if that exists and is stable you can have a spontaneous Wigner crystal. But it would not be a free electron cloud.

@AndersSandberg ProfRob describes a situation where electrons would be separated from protons and then, if protons decayed, they would leave a "hole" which would have a positive net charge. Would this work? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/825340/how-can-the-ions-in-intergalactic-and-interstellar-gas-held-together

@vengaq - No. Proton decay produces positrons that will annihilate the electrons.

In a theorist's notebook, the Wigner crystal phase can be stable with apparently only interacting electrons and nothing else in the model.  The trick is to take away the notion of "expansion" altogether, and you are immune to the mechanical instability.
You either have:

finite volume with some kind of closed boundary condition
finite volume with periodic boundary condition
infinite volume with a finite electron density

But 1 is equivalent to a confining potential, and good luck realizing 2 and 3 in real world.

could the confining force be instated in the form ProfRob described in this other question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/825340/how-can-the-ions-in-intergalactic-and-interstellar-gas-held-together) @T.P.Ho

@vengaq Then you need positive charges to pull the electrons in.  This is still an external confining potential from the point of view of electrons.  And in that case you are far more likely to have electrons localized around the positive charges than forming a crystalline structure.

To follow up on the point made by T.P. Ho (I can't "comment" because I've only just joined and don't have the "reputation") you can make a stable Wigner crystal on the surface of a closed surface such as a sphere (point 1 above) where there are a collection of freely moving charged points on the surface of the sphere. The resulting distribution may have more than one (it usually does) energy minimum, depending on the number of points. The distribution closely resembles a "stealthy hyperuniform distributions" on the surface and a Tammes distribution (the latter which maximises the minimum distance between N points).

could the confining force be instated in the form ProfRob described in this other question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/825340/how-can-the-ions-in-intergalactic-and-interstellar-gas-held-together) @Andrew_UELtd
